# As a new user is signing up, how can i check Unique username?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using Auth.signUp() in my react native app using AWS Cognito/AWS Amplify. I would ideally like a way to check that the username that has been entered (and corresponding email address ideally), are unique and that no one else in the Cognito pool already has those.

If successful, continue sign up, else choose another username.

Currently i do this:

```
await Auth.signUp({
      username,
      password,
      attributes: { email, phone_number }
    })
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Cognito takes care of this unique login name verification.

At the time of creation of the user pool, choose the attributes you require for user registration. It can be `email` or `preferred_username` for example.

If an attribute is required and a user doesn't provide the required attribute, the user cannot register.

If the user provide a required attribute value that is already used by other user,
Cognito will reject it, and return an error:

```
UsernameExistsException: User account already exists
```

You can learn more in [Amazon Cognito Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-usernames).

Answer (score 0):

I believe Shay AshKenazi is incorrect. I have set email as a required attribute and `Cognito` does not stop me from signing up users up with the same email. This is confusing because `Cognito` calls a "Username" the attribute you choose (when creating the user pool) to allow users to sign in with. This attribute can either be a username or email, whichever one you choose and a user attempts to sign up with that username or email then you will get that error

> "UsernameExistsException: User account already exists".

However, I have not been able to get Cogntio to enforce uniqueness for both username and email attributes. If you choose username to be the "Username" then Cognito will only check usernames for uniqueness. Same applies if you choose emails as the "Username".

But I have found a solution to ensuring emails are unique when signing up users - https://dev.to/andthensumm/enforcing-attribute-uniqueness-in-cognito-with-aws-amplify-and-react-263f.

Strangely, if you create a user pool and allow users to login with usernames and verfied emails and then signup two users with the same email but different usernames, Cogntio will allow you to create both users despite having the same email. But note a verified email can only be attached to one user. So if you were to verify the first user's email, then verify the second's email (which is the same as the first user) the first user's email will become unverified, and the second user's email would be verified.